# Relinquish rights on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, permissions

I have a C++ application that runs as administrator (it is compiled with a manifest with `requestedExecutionLevel` set to `requireAdministrator`.

At some point, once all the tasks requiring administration rights are done, I would like to relinquish those rights and perform the remaining tasks as the user that launched the application.

Windows provides the [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but I can't find any way to obtain a token for the user that called the application.

Are there any other ways to do what I have described here?

Comment: you can for example  take current process token, call `CreateRestrictedToken` with `LUA_TOKEN` and impersonate **thread** with this token. but so what ? process token will be unchanged. and thread can at any time remove impersonation token. this not affect another threads in process. with existing process token you can only low it integrity level. say set to medium (this can not be revert back already). this partially restrict process

Comment: You can remove privileges from a token, but not mandatory groups. It used to be that you could swap out the process access token with a restricted token via `NtSetInformationProcess`, but Vista and later don't support this. It's a change for the better since the process may have handles to secured objects that shouldn't be accessible. Instead, you can create a restricted token, with the token security and default DACL extended for the current user and the integrity level lowered to medium. Then call `CreateProcessAsUser` (allowed for a child Token), and wait for the child to exit.

Comment: [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better approach would be to request highestAvailable instead of requireAdministrator in your manifest.  Then, if you find that you are running elevated, just do everything you need to do.  If you find that you are not running elevated:

1. Launch your program again, using ShellExecute with the runAs verb to run it elevated.
2. Have your unelevated process wait for the elevated process to do whatever it needs to do.  (How to know when the elevated process is done is left as an exercise for the implementer.  You also need to worry about what happens if the user does not allow your elevated process to start.)
3. Once the elevated process completes, do the rest of your unelevated work.

If you want to continue with your original plan, [this Raymond Chen blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643/) explains how to start an unelevated process from an elevated process.  (The fact that your manifest requests requireAdministrator may complicate this process.)

Answer (score 0):

msdn:

Enabling a privilege in an access token allows the process to perform system-level actions that it could not previously. Your application should thoroughly verify that the privilege is appropriate to the type of account.

You can check:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619(v=vs.85).aspx

And here is their c++ sample:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "cmcfg32.lib")

BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
    LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
    ) 
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue( 
            NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
            lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup 
            &luid ) )        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
        return FALSE; 
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

    if ( !AdjustTokenPrivileges(
           hToken, 
           FALSE, 
           &tp, 
           sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), 
           (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 
           (PDWORD) NULL) )
    { 
          printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
          return FALSE; 
    } 

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
          printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
          return FALSE;
    } 

    return TRUE;
}
```

And also look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717797(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope it helps.